# sorting data in a multilevel approach like in Excel with PHP & MySql

Tags: php, mysql, excel, sorting

my aim is to be able to sort the data in MySql table in a multilevel approach like in Excel with PHP.

I put a representative image from Excel Sort function. (Since I don't know VBA, I'll try with PHP)

I require for the best efficient, easiest method. I don't have any security concern. (I'll run the PHP function in my computer only for myself)

For my aim, I ask for the related search terms. I searched but I think my terms were not strong enough. regards

[image]

Comment: Perhaps time to read about the `ORDER BY` clause in MySQL: `ORDER BY warrantRecordId ASC, hour ASC, rate ASC, zIndex ASC`

Comment: I'll absolutely, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mark Baker's comment.

after reading https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html, it's clear for me that `ORDER BY` clause in MySQL is a perfect solution.